# How to select tablerows in polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am looking for a way to select another tablerow if you click a different button with polymer. This is what i got so far:

```
<h1 class="page-title">Rooster ( {{username}} )</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Datum:</th>
    <th>Begintijd:</th>
    <th>Eindtijd:</th>
    <th>Vakcode:</th>
    <th>Docent:</th>
    <th>Lokaal:</th>
    <th>Klas:</th>
    <th>Afwezig</th>
  </tr>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lessen}}">
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{item.datum}}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{item.begintijd}}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{item.eindtijd}}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{item.vakcode}}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{item.docent}}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{item.lokaal}}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">{{item.klas}}</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><paper-icon-button icon="add-circle" onclick="document.getElementById('dialog').open()"></paper-icon-button></td>
      <td><paper-dialog id="dialog" transition="paper-dialog-transition-bottom">
      <h1>Afwezig Melden</h1>
      <p>[[item.vakcode]]</p>
      <p>[[item.begintijd]] - [[item.eindtijd]]</p>
      <p></p>
      <p>[[item.lokaal]]</p>
      <p>[[item.klas]]</p>
      <p>[[item.docent]]</p>
      <paper-button raised label="Afmelden" on-click="afwezigHandler"></paper-button>
    </tr>
  </template>
</table>
```

here are some screenshots to better understand what im trying to accomplish:
[screenshot of localhosted application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rhNA.png)

however, if i select the button below it, it will still tell me the data from the row above. This is the same for all the buttons below (only the first row will be shown in the dialog).

thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your dialog ids are same (id="dialog"). Ids should be unique, in your case its repeating and that's the reason why only the first dialog pops up all the time.

Comment: thank you so much, now i can move on with this group project haha ;)